# Postgres Enable TCP/IP Connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, tcp, centos, postgresql-9.4

I have installed postgres-9.4 database server on a CentOS 6.6 system. I am trying to connect to this server from my laptop (connected to the same network. Laptop's ip is 192.168.1.105.  I am running `psql -U postgres -h 192.168.1.52`). The psql command fails with an error message:

```
psql -U postgres -h 192.168.1.52
could not connect to server: COnnection refused
Is the server running on host 192.168.1.52 and accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432?
```

My configuration:
/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/16          trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

/etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

I have restarted the iptables service.

/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

I restart the server as below:

```
[root@cinch-database1 9.4]# service postgresql-9.4 restart
Stopping postgresql-9.4 service:                           [  OK  ]
Starting postgresql-9.4 service:                           [  OK  ]
```

ps aux and grep postgres returns following:

```
ps auxwww | grep postgres
postgres 11460  0.0  0.0 325096 14860 ?        S    01:36   0:00 /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postmaster -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data
postgres 11463  0.0  0.0 180244  1264 ?        Ss   01:36   0:00 postgres: logger process                                
postgres 11465  0.0  0.0 325096  1564 ?        Ss   01:36   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                          
postgres 11466  0.0  0.0 325096  2544 ?        Ss   01:36   0:00 postgres: writer process                                
postgres 11467  0.0  0.0 325096  1496 ?        Ss   01:36   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                            
postgres 11468  0.0  0.0 325508  2340 ?        Ss   01:36   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                   
postgres 11469  0.0  0.0 180376  1476 ?        Ss   01:36   0:00 postgres: stats collector process                       
root     11516  0.0  0.0 103252   844 pts/0    S+   01:41   0:00 grep postgres
```

When I do a netstat on the server and grep for 5432 I get nothing:

```
netstat | grep 5432
```

But `netstat -tulnp` returns this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13227/postmaster
```

Output of 'netstat -l|grep postgres'

```
[root@cinch-database1 pg_log]# netstat -l|grep postgres
tcp        0      0 *:postgres                  *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:postgres                  *:*                         LISTEN
```

But as mentioned earlier psql from my laptop fails to connect to the server.

What am I missing?

Comment: please provide output for `netstat -l|grep "postgres\|5432"`

Comment: Included the `netstat -l|grep postgres` output. I also added 0.0.0.0/0 to the pg_hba.conf file, while looking at other people's configurations, didn't help.

Comment: If you can see the listening is present

Comment: Yes you are right! But I still get the error when executing the rake command from my laptop (connected to the same network).

Comment: have you a firewall setup?

Comment: I don't think so. But I don't know how to verify that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67965/discussion-between---and-septerr).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that the firewall blocks your connections, so just try to disable the firewall with:

```
sudo service iptables stop
```

and then if is pass, setup it correctly.

Comment: Firewall was  the issue. But instead of disabling the firewall, I  moved the lines that were allowing tcp on port 5424 above the lines that reject connections in iptables and it worked (I did not have to stop the firewall) .

Answer (score 1):

It was a firewall issue. I had to move the following two lines in the iptables file earlier in the sequence:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

New iptables:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

After this I restarted iptables service:

```
service iptables restart
```

Now I can connect to postgres from my laptop.